# ASP.NET: HttpApplication lifecycle

Tags: asp.net, response, httpmodule

In an HttpModule, I'd like to intercept the Response after the HttpResponse.Headers collection has been set but before the body of the Response has been added to the Response Stream. Would this be on the HttpContext.Current.PreSendRequestContent event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it would be [HttpApplication.PreSendRequestHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.presendrequestheaders.aspx) and there might be content already in the Response stream (even the entire body) waiting to be sent after the headers.